# When to use request scoped beans vs passing parameters down the stack?

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns

I am exposing an API, and I extract a `client` parameter from the request header.
This parameter is then used from the business logic, to apply customer-specific rules, down to the connection layer, where it drives which external system I will call.

We are having discussions with a colleague on whether we should use a request scoped bean to store this parameter and make it readily available everywhere in the stack, or whether we should pass this value down as a method argument, or a mix of both.

The request-scoped bean is simple - you store the value and can access it everywhere. On the other hand, you hide the actual needs of your services by not exposing the actual parameters it needs.

Are there best practices in this case? How would you handle this situation?

Comment: Using it as a method parameter might make unit-testing of those methods easier.

Answer (score 1):

What we ended up doing:

- Expose the parameters in business service signatures, to make it really clear what the methods depend on to perform their job
- Use a request-scoped bean for transverse concerns, like logging or the access layer.

The reason is that transverse services typically need a wide array of information, and passing this information through the business layer pollutes the requirements of the methods, since all methods will have to accept the same N parameters.